# Am I decoding quoted printable bounce messages containing a VERP-encoded addresses correctly in PHP?

Tags: php

Thanks to SO, I was able to save myself some time by avoiding writing my own function to decode quoted printable emails and instead use PHP's `decode_quoted_printable()` function.

However, I very quickly ran into a problem. I have a bounce notification email that I need to decode and display in the browser and the **body** of the email contains the original email headers, which includes the original source address, which was VERP-encoded so that I could associate the bounce back with the corresponding user in the database.

The body of the bounce notification email includes this snippet:

```
------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------

Return-path: <blah+user=af.com@mydomain.com>
```

The problem is that `quoted_printable_decode()` uses the '=' character as a special character to indicate that it might have to do some special decoding. In the case of '=af' (\x3D6166) it decides to translate it into \xAF, which is the Unicode code point for the Macron character. When I later run this through `htmlentities()` this gets converted to the appropriate HTML code for the Macron character, so I end up with this output in the browser:

Return-path: <blah+user¯.com@mydomain.com>

Of course, this doesn't happen for all sequences starting with '=', only the ones that PHP decides it can convert into meaningful Unicode code points. The alternative `imap_qprint()` exhibits the same behaviour.

Oh, and I'm running PHP 5.3.8.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just how `quoted_printable_decode()` is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

After a little more research I realised that the only two escape sequences in the encoded emails were equals signs at the end of each line to identify where a line feed had been removed and '=3D' to denote where real equals signs were supposed to be.

So I simply replaced the call to `quoted_printable_decode()` with this one-liner:

```
$decoded_body = str_replace( array( "=\n", '=3D' ), array( '', '=' ), $email_body );
```

I realise this won't deal with any Unicode data that could theoretically appear in the email, but given that I'm controlling the content of the messages that are bouncing back, I can pretty much guarantee that they won't. So keep that in mind if you decide to use this solution yourself.